# how can i fix that android studio does not accept or detect my xml layouts when doing setContentView()?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Dunno why but every time I create a **new** **Activity**, **Fragment** or whatever it says that the **layout doesn't exist** (when the layout is generated with the activity) and I can clearly see the XML file in my layout folder but the android studio says it doesn't exist.

Any help?

[The error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kXKk.png)

i let u a image where u cant see the R.layout.etc marking an error
at the left u can see the folder layout with the correct layout

Comment: Sometimes it happens. You can Go to Build Menu > Clear Project and everything should work. If it still doesn't work then you need to Invalidate Cache and restart the Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to Restart your `Android Studio`.

You will face many such silly errors in future So, its always better to `restart` or `clean Project` But always prefer to `Restart` Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to file-->Invalidate cache/Restart.
Android Studio will detect the layout file.

Happy Coding!